# Trying to display a warning message on a btnsubmit_click function in vb.net when the invoice is in use

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net

The sql script is validating the use of the invoice type and invoice. I need to add the check and message in the If (`Me.txtMasterId.Text <> "0"`) method..

```vb
Protected Sub btnsubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnsubmit.Click
    If (Not DataForm.ValidateForm) Then
        TransRepo.ModifyStatusName(gUser.CompanyId, Me.txtMasterId.Text, Me.txtStatusName.Text, chkIsPmtPlanFee.Checked, chkIsAttorneyFee.Checked, Me.cboStatus.SelectedValue, Me.txtId.Text, ParseDec(Me.txtExpenseLimit.Text), chkUserSpecPayTo.Checked)

        ShowPanel(Me.pnlItemList, Me.Form)
        ListOptions(Me.txtMasterId.Text)
        SetPageHeader("List Status Name")

        If (Me.txtId.Text = "0") Then
            ShowConfirmation(Me.lblItemFrmMsg, "New name Added")

            If (Me.txtMasterId.Text <> "0") Then
                ShowConfirmation(Me.lblItemFrmMsg, "Status Name Saved")
            Else
                DataForm.DisplayError(Me.lblFrmErr)
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

```vb
    Dim cn As MySqlConnection
    Dim rdr As MySqlDataReader
    Try
        Dim Sql = "SELECT invoice_type.id
                   FROM invoice_type_fee
                   INNER JOIN invoice_name ON invoice_type.id = invoice_type_fee.`id`
                   WHERE invoice_name.`is_active` = 1
                   AND invoice_type_fee.`is_active` = 1
                   AND (invoice_type_fee.`fee_invoice_id` = @invoiceTyID
                   OR invoice_type_fee.`fee_late_invoicetype_id` = @invoiceTypeID LIMIT 1"
        rdr.Read()
        If (rdr.HasRows) Then
            Dim message As String = "....."
            Status.Visible = False
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "alert", "alert('" & message & "');", True)
            'If (invoicetype = "1") Then
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no reader. You never call `ExecuteReader` so there's no reader to read. You seem to think that it is `Read` that executes the SQL but it is not. `ExecuteReader` executes the SQL and then `Read` is used to get the data from the result set. I just realised that there isn't even a command in your case. You need to create a command to execute, execute it, then read the results

There's no point getting any data though, because all you care about is whether there is data, not what it is. That means that `HasRows` is all you need in that case, e.g.

```vb
Using connection As New MySqlConnection("connection string here"),
      command As New MySqlCommand(sql, connection)
    connection.Open()

    Using reader = command.ExecuteReader()
        If reader.HasRows Then
            'The query produced a non-empty result set.
        End If
    End Using
End Using
```

A better option would be to add a `COUNT` to your SQL, call `ExecuteScalar` and then check whether the result is zero or not.

```vb
Dim Sql = "SELECT COUNT(invoice_type.id)
           FROM invoice_type_fee
           INNER JOIN invoice_name ON invoice_type.id = invoice_type_fee.`id`
           WHERE invoice_name.`is_active` = 1
           AND invoice_type_fee.`is_active` = 1
           AND (invoice_type_fee.`fee_invoice_id` = @invoiceTyID
           OR invoice_type_fee.`fee_late_invoicetype_id` = @invoiceTypeID LIMIT 1"

Using connection As New MySqlConnection("connection string here"),
      command As New MySqlCommand(sql, connection)
    connection.Open()

    If CInt(command.ExecuteScalar()) > 0 Then
        'There are matching records.
    End If

End Using
```